# Exchange - Multiple users send/rec from mailbox

Tags: exchange, exchange-2010

I've got a mailbox that several users want to send/receive from and I'm wondering best practices for achieving this.

Traditionally I'd give each user send/receive on the mailbox and let autodiscover handle the rest but I'm not sure this is the best way.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Sounds about right to me; grant the accounts the permissions to access the mailbox and send as and read the mail from the mailbox, and then show them how to send as rather than on behalf of with the FROM being that shared mailboxes email address, and ensure you configure the security within Exchange accordingly. At least with Exchange 2010 this is how I've done it in the past. Having auto discovery attach the mailbox when applicable or doing it explicitly should be fine as well depending on the configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure to setup the mailbox as a 'Shared Mailbox', this means the account is disabled by default so nobody can logon directly and you save on a mailbox license. Only other way would be to setup a mail-enabled public folder.

Some people also assign the shared mailbox access to a mail-enabled security group which would allow other users to administer the access rights. This can work well if a lot of people need access and users are always changing, otherwise it can be a bit of overkill.